# Java validation @min @max annotion for null values

Tags: java, validation, max, min

I have put validation for the following field,

```
@Min(1)
@Max(500)
private int length;
```

however, the length isn't a required field but when I didn't give the "length" in the input, I got this error:

```
   "Validation error, message = must be greater than or equal to 1, path = length"
```

Looking at the @min and @max documentation, it says "null element is considered valid".   I know that. If @min @max is only for primitive type, then why the documentation mentions "null" element is considered valid?  Can someone let me know how to fix the validation problem?  Many thanks.

Comment: And _when_ do you expect `length` to be `null`?

Comment: I didn't expect it to be null.  I just don't know how to pass the validation  when length is not provided.  I thought ""null element is considered valid" meant the scenario of "not provided"

Comment: An `int` can't ever be `null`, it's a primitive type. If you want it to be nullable, you have to make it an `Integer`.

Comment: When you don't expect it to be null, then why do you quote that line? And the "min" annotation makes it quite clear that you ___can't___ pass validation when you don't provide a proper value.

Comment: *"If min max is only for primitive type"* - That assumption is wrong.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For optional integer values, you may use `Integer` instead of `int`, since an `int` variable cannot be null and will have 0 as a default value.
With an `Integer`, length will be null by default and you should be able to pass the validation.